# Map a URL to a local file in Windows

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, redirection, url, browser-cache

Is there a way to map a URL to a local file so that when IE sends a request for that URL it gets the content from a local file?

For example: `http://www.example.com/file.zip` ---> `C:\file.zip`

I'm trying to achieve a permanent "cache" for some specific files so that IE always retrieve those files from the harddrive. And then I need a way to change the content of those files if needed.

Something like a permanent entry in the IE cache that never expires and is never deleted.

**EDIT:**
Could this be done with a proxy autoconfiguration file? (those with .pac extension)

Comment: This presumably only needs to work on your machine?

Comment: Yes, only in my PC and for IE only (although a solution for all browsers is fine as well)

Comment: Can you not use the `file://` protocol directly? Or does it have to be a request for an external file that is routed internally?

Comment: Also, do you have control over this external site? Or is it just some arbitrary website?

Comment: Yes, it's for a third party website, I can't change the URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a couple of tools that do exactly this.

- [**Fiddler**](http://www.fiddler2.com/)
  Check out video #2 in [this page](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/video/default.asp) for the AutoResponder function.
- [**Charles Proxy**](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)
  Read about its Map Local Tool [here](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/map-local/).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you'd need this. It would worry me for security issues (does he really need to redirect www.mybank.com like that?) But lets assume you have a good reason.

You ask for a hard task; how is the cache to be updated, if it never hits origin servers? What is the criterion for a cache reload? "Never change, unless I want it to change for some reason"

I think the closest you can get is a caching proxy. Id check the docs on [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) to see if you can lock certain content in. This won't work (by design) for https sites though.

Comment: Oh, for debugging certain things.